# Memory Leak in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory-leaks

For making that fast, I'll explain my implementation and then the problem =):

I have an object:

```
Class myClass{
  ......attrs......
  ......getters and setters......

  public void setOnMyClassChangeListener(MyClassChangeListener listener){
      this.listener=listener;
  }
}
```

And a ListView monitorizing objects of that class with that method in it ArrayAdapter:

```
static class ViewHolder {
        View view1,view2,view3.....;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.templaterow, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.view1=.....;
        holder.view2=.....;
        holder.view3=.....;
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
    MyClass object= items.get(position)
    object.setOnMyClassChangeListener(MyClassChangeListener(){
          public void onMyClassChangeListener(MyClass obj){
               holder.view1.setXX(obj.getValue1());
               holder.view2.setXX(obj.getValue2());
               ......
          }
    }
    );
}
```

So I think I'm leaking memory because the listener keep set after exit the ListActity and then the holder is leaked right?

Is there a method better than iterate the Adapter in the onStop removing the listeners?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a better method: don't set such a listener on your object which has references to the Views.

Instead you just modify the model (MyClass) and then call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() on the ArrayAdapter. The ListView will redraw then.